# Access encrypted database from H2 console

Tags: java, database, encryption, h2

I want to store my H2 database as an encrypted file and access its web interface.

I configured H2 database so that I can access web interface to manipulate the database under `console/db` address.

When I do not use encryption everything works fine.

When I add `CIPHER=AES` to `db.url` I cannot log into the database and get below exception:

```
File corrupted while reading record: null. Possible solution: use the recovery tool [90030-191] 90030/90030 (Help)
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Uszkodzenie pliku podczas wczytywania rekordu: null
File corrupted while reading record: null. Possible solution: use the recovery tool [90030-191]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:345)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:168)
    at org.h2.mvstore.db.MVTableEngine$Store.convertIllegalStateException(MVTableEngine.java:195)
    at org.h2.mvstore.db.MVTableEngine$Store.open(MVTableEngine.java:167)
    at org.h2.mvstore.db.MVTableEngine.init(MVTableEngine.java:99)
    at org.h2.engine.Database.getPageStore(Database.java:2460)
    at org.h2.engine.Database.open(Database.java:692)
    at org.h2.engine.Database.openDatabase(Database.java:270)
    at org.h2.engine.Database.<init>(Database.java:264)
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.openSession(Engine.java:65)
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.openSession(Engine.java:175)
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.createSessionAndValidate(Engine.java:153)
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.createSession(Engine.java:136)
    at org.h2.engine.Engine.createSession(Engine.java:28)
    at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.connectEmbeddedOrServer(SessionRemote.java:349)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.<init>(JdbcConnection.java:107)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.<init>(JdbcConnection.java:91)
    at org.h2.Driver.connect(Driver.java:72)
    at org.h2.server.web.WebServer.getConnection(WebServer.java:735)
    at org.h2.server.web.WebApp.login(WebApp.java:955)
    at org.h2.server.web.WebApp.process(WebApp.java:211)
    at org.h2.server.web.WebApp.processRequest(WebApp.java:170)
    at org.h2.server.web.WebServlet.doGet(WebServlet.java:125)
    at org.h2.server.web.WebServlet.doPost(WebServlet.java:162)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:121)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:522)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1095)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:672)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1502)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1458)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Store header is corrupt: nio:/home/robak/db/adzfo.mv.db [1.4.191/6]
    at org.h2.mvstore.DataUtils.newIllegalStateException(DataUtils.java:773)
    at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore.readStoreHeader(MVStore.java:603)
    at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore.<init>(MVStore.java:353)
    at org.h2.mvstore.MVStore$Builder.open(MVStore.java:2888)
    at org.h2.mvstore.db.MVTableEngine$Store.open(MVTableEngine.java:154)
    ... 47 more
```

#### Database Configuration

```
db.driver=org.h2.Driver
db.url=jdbc:h2:file:~/db/app_name;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE;CIPHER=AES
db.username=user
db.password=password
```

#### Servlet Context

```
  private void configureDatabaseConsole(ServletContext servletContext) {
    ServletRegistration.Dynamic h2Servlet = servletContext.addServlet("h2console", WebServlet.class);
    h2Servlet.setLoadOnStartup(2);
    h2Servlet.addMapping("/console/db/*");
  }
```

#### Data source

```
  @Bean
  public DataSource dataSource() {
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName(getProperty(DRIVER));
    dataSource.setUrl(getProperty(URL));
    dataSource.setUsername(getProperty(USERNAME));
    dataSource.setPassword(FILE_PASSWORD + " " + getProperty(PASSWORD));
    return dataSource;
  }
```

What should I do to have an encrypted database as a file on a hard drive and to access its console via web interface?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you using the right password. Quoting from the H2 documentation [File Encryption](http://h2database.com/html/features.html#file_encryption)

```
 The encryption algorithm is set in the database URL, and the file
 password is specified in the password field, before the user 
 password. A single space separates the file password and the user   
 password; the file password itself may not contain spaces. File 
 passwords and user passwords are case sensitive. Here is an example 
 to connect to a password-encrypted database:

 Class.forName("org.h2.Driver");
 String url = "jdbc:h2:~/test;CIPHER=AES";
 String user = "sa";
 String pwds = "filepwd userpwd";
 conn = DriverManager.
     getConnection(url, user, pwds);
```

If you don't provide the correct password you won't get a connection.

Comment: Yes, password is correct ```dataSource.setPassword(FILE_PASSWORD + " " + getProperty(PASSWORD));```. This must be something else.

Comment: Did you create a new fresh db when you enabled the encryption?

Comment: Yes I did. I think that it may be related to ```AUTO_SERVER=TRUE``` option, but I still haven't found the answer.

Comment: Did you try to access it without `AUTO_SERVER` within the connection string (leaving AES there)? ps: You can also access the H2 running in server mode using any generic JDBC client like SquirrelSQL. Maybe you can check whether you can access the database via that way.

Comment: ps: i quickly looked at the H2 [MVStore](http://code.metager.de/source/xref/h2database/h2/src/main/org/h2/mvstore/MVStore.java) code and during initialization of the class it seems to read store, see line 336 (encrypted in your case)  and then immediately attempts to read the header (method readStoreHeader()  line 548) and this is also the method that throws the exception you see, (line 593).